# Custom Base64 Encoder Doesn't Encode Correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, encode, rfc

I decided to make my own Base64 encoder and decoder, despite there already being a module for this in the standard library. It's just meant to be a fun project. However, the encoder, for some reason, incorrectly encodes some characters, and I haven't had luck with debugging. I've tried to follow the model found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to a tee. I believe the problem has to do with the underlying conversion to binary format, but I'm not sure.

**Code**:

```py
def encode_base64(data):
    raw_bits = ''.join('0' + bin(i)[2:] for i in data)
    # First bit is usually (always??) 0 in ascii characters
    
    split_by_six = [raw_bits[i: i + 6] for i in range(0, len(raw_bits), 6)]
    
    if len(split_by_six[-1]) < 6: # Add extra zeroes if necessary
        split_by_six[-1] = split_by_six[-1] + ((6 - len(split_by_six[-1])) * '0')
    
    padding = 2 if len(split_by_six) % 2 == 0 else 1
    if len(split_by_six) % 4 == 0: # See if padding is necessary
        padding = 0
    
    indexer = ([chr(i) for i in range(65, 91)] # Base64 Table
         + [chr(i) for i in range(97, 123)]
         + [chr(i) for i in range(48, 58)]
         + ['+', '/'])
    
    return ''.join(indexer[int(i, base=2)] for i in split_by_six) + ('=' * padding)
```

When I run the following sample code, I get the incorrect value, and you can see below:

```py
print(base_64(b'any carnal pleasure'))
# OUTPUT: YW55QMbC5NzC2IHBsZWFzdXJl=
# What I should be outputting: YW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4=
```

For some odd reason, the first few characters are correct, and then the rest aren't. I am happy to answer any questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `bin()` function doesn't include leading zeroes, so the length of a binary representation will vary:

```
>>> bin(1)
'0b1'
>>> bin(255)
'0b11111111'
>>> bin(ord("a"))
'0b1100001'
>>> bin(ord(" "))
'0b100000'
```

In your input, `a`, `n`, and `y` all have one leading zero in their binary representation, so the length of `bin(i)` is consistent. But the binary representation of `' '` has two leading zeroes, so `bin(i)` is one bit shorter than you expect, and the rest of `raw_bits` gets misaligned.

To fix this, make sure you pad the binary representation with leading zeroes until it's 8 characters. I don't think there's a particularly elegant way to do this, but you can use `format(ord(i), "#010b")[2:]` to make sure the full representation is 10 characters, then discard the `0b`, leaving the 8 that you care about.